# Why did pharaoh not want the frogs to be immediately removed?

Tags: plagues-makkos, va-eira

Why did pharaoh not want the frogs to be immediately removed?Why did he request that they be dealt with "tomorrow"

Comment: When composing a question it always helps to bring the sources of your clams - please provide the verses that show that.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question Snoozy. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: From what I understood, he wanted to pick when he thought they wouldn't leave -- if he has said "now" and they were on their way out then he couldn't attribute their removal to Hashem. He picked a time in the future and Moshe said "fine -- Hashem can make it happen whenever."

Answer (score 4):

[Va'eirah 8:5-6](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9869#v5)

> And Moses said to Pharaoh, "Boast [of your superiority] over me. For
>   when shall I entreat for you, for your servants, and for your people,
>   to destroy the frogs from you and from your houses, [that] they should
>   remain only in the Nile? "
>
> And he [Pharaoh] said, "For tomorrow." And he [Moses] said, "As you
>   say, in order that you should know that there is none like the Lord,
>   our God.

Rav Hirsch points out that Par'o was actually trying to *outsmart* Moshe. He knew that the plague of blood had ended by itself. He thought that if he said *today*, the plague would have ended anyway. By saying *tomorrow* he would be able to claim that Moshe was just a powerful magician and the frogs would disappear immediately, because Moshe would have set up the removal already as soon as he was called to Par'o.

> The motive for Moshe making the exit of the plague itself into an אות,
>   and not simply undertaking Pharoah's request, lay in the request
>   itself. Had Pharaoh been already convinced, he would simply have let
>   the people go. But as it was, it was apparent that all he wanted was
>   to be freed from the plague. That is why the departure of the frogs
>   was itself to be a further instructive אות; perhaps this would produce
>   the desired result. Accordingly, the frogs are not simply to go back
>   from where they came, that could be taken as merely the cessation of
>   Hashem's activity and a return to normal conditions. They are to die,
>   but as emphasized repeatedly ביאר תשארנה, not all of them, that could
>   again be taken as some phenomenon of Nature (cf. V9).